Why does transaction value have impact on transaction fee in Ethereum?
I am sending a transaction to Sepolia test network from browsers. The code I have is something like:
provider.request({
        method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
        params: [
          {
            from,
            to,
            gas,
            maxFeePerGas,
            value,
            data: await contract.methods
              .testTransfer()
              .encodeABI(),
          },
        ],
      });

When I change the value parameter in the request body, the fee for this transaction is very different. For example, if I send the value as 100000000000000 which is 0.0001 eth it will cost 0.007 eth fee. However, If I send the value as 1000000000000000 which is 0.001 eth, it will cost 1.16 eth fee.
I wonder why there is so much different in gas when change the value in transaction?

Are you having some checks/conditions related to msg.value in the contract function that you're calling?

No it doesn't have any check on msg.value in the code.
